# LibGDX Android blackscreens at a certain screen

Tags: android, libgdx, eclipse-adt, android-debug

To explain the Situation: I've got a LibGDX Game runnig without Problems as Desktop Project...
But as soon as I install the App onto my Android device, It only shows the first screen... In this case, it is a Menu-Screen which obviously needn't much resouces...The Textures are not in resolutions of powers of two but I'm using OpenGl2.0.

When I'm now changing the Screen to the actual Game-Screen, my device just blackscreens. This Screen contains a Box2d World with lots of Objects, a big Texture(6500x877) and an animation. My guess is, that there are Problems concerning the abilities of my Processor(Nvidia Tegra2). Is there any chance of debugging the Game during taking a look at the CPU load? I can't use an Emulator cause this won't work with LibGDX.

Comment: Did you tried it with a smaller texture? That texture is to big for and mobile device i think. And yes you can activate the CPU load at your device at the development Settings

Comment: Note: Most mobile devices have a texture limit of around 2048x2048 and I believe 1024x1024 for some GPUs. If you are working with a single texture larger than these, there is no guarantee they will even load and you will not see them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OpenGL Tracer to get more information about what is going on: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html.  Also: [OpenGL debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999784/opengl-debugging)

The tracer tool requires that you're running on a recent Android release (4.1 or better)

You can also programmatically invoke `Gdx.gl.glGetError()` sporadically in your code to see if any OpenGL commands are triggering an error.  See [When Should One Call glGetError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963325/when-should-one-call-glgeterror)

You can query the OpenGL runtime for the largest supported texture dimension with

```
IntBuffer max = BufferUtils.newIntBuffer(16); // See http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=1314.0;wap2
max.clear();
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, max);
int maxTexDim = max.get(0);
```

In your case I suspect you'll get 4096 or 2048 back ...